# jQuery .html() Function

Tags: jquery

The following code creates li from div's but the divs still appear in the source, what have I missed?:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var makeLI = $("div").html("<li class='blue'>" +
    "Here is a new &lt;li &gt; element.</li>");

    $("body").append("<ul>");

    $("ul").append(makeLI);
  });
```

A publication states:

> Navigate to the file in your browser. The  elements are converted
>   to elements with the text we want displayed.

However in FF 6 the div's remain:

```
<div><li class="blue">Here is a new &lt;li &gt; element.</li></div>
```

------------------Complete Code------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
 <style>
  .blue { color:blue; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Rewriting three &lt;div&gt; elements</h1>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

</body>
</html>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   var makeLI = $("div").html("<li class='blue'>" +
    "Here is a new &lt;li &gt; element.</li>");


    $("body").append("<ul>");

    $("ul").append(makeLI);
  });
```

Comment: is it ONLY in FF 6? it's not finished software, maybe it's because of that if it's ONLY in 6.

Answer (score 2):

`makeLI` *is* the `div` element. The `li` is a child of it. Of course if you append the `div` somewhere it will be there. If you only want to append the `li` element, you have to call `children`:

```
$("ul").append(makeLI.children());
```

Or simply omit the `div`:

```
$('body').append($("<ul />").append("<li class='blue'>" +
"Here is a new &lt;li &gt; element.</li>"));
```

---

Btw. the `div` will be there in *all* browsers. You might not see it, because browsers tend to correct invalid HTML. A `div` element inside a `ul` element is not valid and it will probably be moved *after* the `ul`. Nevertheless, you should create **valid** HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating that div in the $("div") skip that and you should be set

```
var $li = $("<li>");
$li.html("Here is a new &lt;li &gt; element.");
$li.addClass('blue');
```